# how do i get json response from ajax error method

Tags: ajax, laravel, axios

I am trying to create a user authentication using vue and laravel, after register  button click,  I am sending the form data to the create user controller where I have coded in this manner

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'firstname'  =>  'required',
        'lastname'   =>  'required',
        'email'      =>  'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'   =>  'required|min:8',
        'phoneno'    =>  'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return response($validator->getMessageBag()->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY); 
    }

    $firstname = $request->firstname;
    $lastname = $request->lastname;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $phoneno = $request->phoneno;
    return response($request, Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

and from my frontend, i am makking an ajax request using axios, i am sending the form data as:

```
    let formdata = this.user;
    axios.post('/api/user', {
        data: formdata
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

But in cases where there are errors, i dont get the json i passed from the 
`$validator->fails()` check i only get to see:
[image: image from registering with errors]

Is there a way i can get the json i passed on error?

Comment: Are you positive you are meeting the validation requirements? Have you tried looking at what might be in the request? `dd($request->all());`

Comment: positive, the form data gets to the controller, my concern isnt about the data getting to the controller but rather about getting the errors as json back to the view...
if i made the data pass all validation checks, i wont get any problems

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din the data gets sent to the controller, i just want to be able to get the errors in the message bag when validation fails

Comment: Have you entered "Accept : application/json" in the header?

Comment: @rezabaghiee The answer solved this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

`return response()->json($validator->errors(), Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)`

## EDIT:

`error.response.data` has the error messages

`error.response.status` has the error code

Comment: same output the 422 response can be seen from the console but not the data

Comment: check the image from the question, that is the output from 
`console.log(error)` but i actually want the data i sent from the controller.

Comment: please add this `console.log('errorType', typeof error);` and post the message

Comment: output is `object`

Comment: actually you can see the available attributes of error object in the console, I think you need these two attributes: `error.response.data` `error.response.status`, log them and post what u got please

Comment: `console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status)`

Comment: wow, thanks `error.response.data` contains the errors from the validation